# Alamofire & base64string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Issue trying to add a `base64String` into the parameters array in `Alamofire`, not sure if anyone is aware of this limitation or is it something to do with `Swift`.

```
    var  base64String:String = ""
        if((testImageRow.value) != nil) {
            var img:UIImage = testImageRow.value as! UIImage
            var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
            base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed)
        }

    var params:[String: AnyObject] = ["image": base64String]
    myAPI.post("image/update", parameters:params , delegate: self,tag:0)
```

Below is the error received

```
GET Error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation 
couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" 
(Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7fbda203c110
{NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Optional()` parameter appears only when a return data has not correctly specified the type of value stored in a variable.

First start with the response URL, and see what is really happening. You can NSLog `[NSString stringWithUTF8String: [data bytes]]` for the nice version of data, but do not forget to watch the HTTP response. Log `[Description answer]`.

If the `POST` method is not implemented in your code I suggest you add to your MyApi question could assume that occupy `extension Alamofire.Request`

```
var params: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = []
var addthis = [
    "image": ""
]
params.append(addthis)
```

This way I codified an image:

```
 var pic :NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(cameraView.image, 0.5)
 var str = pic.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))
```

Comment: It's failing before it can get to post.

Comment: error (Error 3840. Cocoa) is caused by improper parsing of JSON especially Alamofire, you can try this: `var params: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] = []`, and I say that this is going to help you more clearly.

Comment: The parameters if  i remove the base64String parses correctly, but if i add the base64String it fails. I'm starting to wonder if there is a "{" character or some other special one somewhere in the base64 string that is causing it to fail.

Comment: I added as he used the base64 of an image in my answer.

Comment: I was already doing the base64 encoding exactly the way you have shown, but no luck sending in base64 to Alamofire

Comment: Using postman I am to post image with generated base64String, but I am not able to post it using simulator or phone.

Comment: Hey have you got the answer @Mr.Bista I am getting the same problem.